# How do I accept large sized CSV file over API integration into Salesforce

Tags: rest, salesforce, integration

I have a use case where an external system will generate a large sized CSV file of around 10 MB size on daily basis. This file needs to be pushed into Salesforce over API integration (automatically).
Once the CSV file is into Salesforce, we are good to write logic to process the file row by row to insert a record into Salesforce object.
But the question is, how do I receive around 10Mb CSV file into Salesforce over REST API?

Please make a note that this will be point to point integration, no integration platform (MuleSoft or ESB) in between.

Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated!

I don't want to use Dataloader or the import of file should not be manual. External system will generate a file and needs a mechanism to push the file into Salesforce.

Comment: Would the bulkAPI work for this purpose? (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_preparing.htm)